# Multiboot with Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7

I have been using Ubuntu for a couple of years and now I need some version of Windows alongside it.  So, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate Black Edition on the free partition I had. Now I cannot get my computer to boot in Ubuntu.  I have looked at the BIOS and don't see a simple solution to this.

Does anybody know why I can't boot into Ubuntu and/or how to fix it so I can?

Comment: You say "no matter the options win7 is always selected". Does that mean you do get a boot loader choice screen? There are utilities that let you restore the boot loader. Does [this one](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy. Windows installer saved his own `MBR` on your HDD. so Windows is booting by default (instead of GRUB).

You have to :

- Boot from cd/usb into any distribution of linux,
- Mount your system partition,
- Chroot into your filesystem and
- run grub-install as root.

This should help.

Comment: Lol. Of course windows would do that... Thanks a lot. Was hoping to avoid booting off of a flash (don't think I have one around). Oh well. Will do it when I get home from work!

Answer (score 1):

You have to (and you can) reinstall grub.

I followed this :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Please note that a question on http://askUbuntu.com would probably ensure a better support on this delicate problem (I'm sure you don't want to do dangerous things when playing with your MBR).